# Twitter4j Search method

Tags: twitter4j

I used Twitter4J for search of tweets. I used the Query class. I created my own tweets with my desired phrase to search to try it. But it doesn't seem to see my tweet when I search for it. So how can I make sure to know if I can search tweets?

My code is:

```
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(getConfig().build()).getInstance();
    Query query = new Query(URLEncoder.encode("#MatthewPogi"));
    QueryResult qr = twitter.search(query);
    List<Status> statuses = qr.getTweets();
    for(Status status: statuses) {
        System.out.println(status.getId() + " " + status.getText() + " " + status.getSource());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
*Query query = new Query("#MatthewPogi");
            QueryResult result;
            do {
                result = twitter.search(query);
                List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
                for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                    Date createdAt = tweet.getCreatedAt();
                    System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getUser().getCreatedAt() + " - " +tweet.getText() + " - " +tweet.getUser().getLocation());
                }
            } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = new Query("ekkada");
QueryResult result;
do {
    result = twitter.search(query);
    List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
    int i = 0;
    for (Status tweet : tweets) {
        fw.write("#" + (i++) + "  " + tweet.getCreatedAt() + " @" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
        fw.write("\n");
    }
} while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
```